# Plot pre-calculated confidence intervals in seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a dataframe containing confidence intervals of means on parameters `'likes, 'retweets', 'followers', 'pics'` for 4 samples: `ikke-aktant, laser, umbrella, mask`. All values are a list containing the confidence intervals, e.g. `[8.339078253365264, 9.023388831788864]`, which is the confidence interval for likes in the laser-sample. A picture of the dataframe can be seen here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOgty.jpg

I want to plot it in a seaborn pointplot, where y represents the four samples, and x is likes.

So far I have:

`ax = sns.pointplot(x="likes", data=df_boot, hue='sample', join=False)`

Which returns error:

`` TypeError: Horizontal orientation requires numeric `x` variable. ``

I guess this is because x is a list. Is there a way to plot my confidence intervals using pointplot?

Comment: The picture of the df is not visible.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't noticed. I just added a link to the image.

Comment: So do you want to plot the first value of each list in your df or the second one?

Comment: I want to plot the value that is exactly 'in between' the two values, as well as the values on each side, like in this plot: https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-pointplot-6.png Where days are sample titles, and x is likes/retweets/etc

Comment: I'm not sure if that's going to work. Looking at your data you would have an x-axis ranging from 0 to 66400 because 'followers' has a large data, while the other variables have ranges between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yeah, sry. I mean different plots, each containing either like or retweet, etc. Only on one parameter for alle samples

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using data that are already confidence intervals. Pointplot expects 'raw' data like the example dataset found here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/tips.csv. So why not use the data that you used to calculate those confidence intervals?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be right about that. I will just use seaborn to calculate the CI instead. Thanks for helping! You can submit your comment as an answer, if you would like for me to mark it as a solution

Comment: Just did that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using data that are already confidence intervals. Pointplot expects 'raw' data like the example dataset found here: github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/tips.csv. So why not use the data that you used to calculate those confidence intervals?